# JQuery multiple event handlers in document.ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, spring

I'm building web application using JQuery/AJAX and Spring MVC.

I've an html horizontal menu like below

```
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
   <li class='active'><a href='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/add' class="navlink"><span>Add </span></a></li>
   <li><a href='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/update' class="navlink"><span>Update </span></a></li>
   <li><a href='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/delete' class="navlink"><span>Delete </span></a></li>
   <li><a href='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/deleteAll' class="navlink"><span>Delete All s</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
    <div id="endpoint" style="border:1px" >
      <form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/setEndPoint"
                  id="epform" method="post" >
      <p><label for="endPoint"> Set Endpoint: </label>
            <input id="endPoint" type="text" name="endPoint" size="75"/>
            <input value="Save" class="button" id="epsave" type="submit"/></p>
      </form>
      <p><span style="width:75"></span></p>
</div>
<div id='content' style="margin-top: 1cm;"></div>
```

and then , I've a JQuery function, that does a JQuery get of the corresponding HTML page from server and loads the result in the #content div.

I've an additional text field, whose value, I need to save to session in one of the spring controllers. The text field value is also an ajax post to the corresponding URL, like below:

The JQuery script that I've so far is as below

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

      $('.navlink').click(function(e) {
            $("#cssmenu .active").removeClass("active");
            $(this).parent().addClass("active");
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#content').load( $(this).prop("href"));
            return true;
      });


$( "#epsave" ).bind("click", function(event){
      alert("Ajaxing ... ");

      event.preventDefault();

      $.ajax({
            url: $( this ).attr("action"),
            type: "POST",
            data: $( "#epform" ).serialize(),
            success: function(resp) {
                  console.log("What Respone?: " + resp);
                  $( "span" ).empty();
                  $( "span" ).text(resp).show();
            },
            error: function(err) {
                  $( "span" ).empty();
                  $( "span" ).text(err).show();
            }
      });
});
});
</script>
```

The .navlink is working fine, in which it is showing the pages for the links, however, the #epsave function is not working. The ajax post for #epsave is not posting the request to the server. The html navigation menu is itself showing up multiple times. What am I doing wrong? Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You have to handle `submit` event instead of `click`. Try this code:

```
$( "#epform" ).submit(function(event){

  console.log("Ajaxing ... ");

  event.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({
        url: $( this ).attr("action"),
        type: "POST",
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(resp) {
              console.log("What Respone?: " + resp);
              $( "span" ).empty();
              $( "span" ).text(resp).show();
        },
        error: function(err) {
              $( "span" ).empty();
              $( "span" ).text(err).show();
        }
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your click-handler `$(this)` is the clicked button, not the form tag. Thus there is no `action` attribute on `$(this)`. Change

```
url: $( this ).attr("action"),
```

to

```
url: $( this ).parent().attr("action"),
```